# Android activities, same layout as a template inject different content layout

Tags: android

I was wondering what some of the best practices of achieving this might be.

I'm looking to take a `layout file` that has similiar structure, so I can use it throughout the app in different activities.

So something like this: `activity_base.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to inject a `layout file` into this include programatically inside of each activity?

So if I have a content file for each activity `content_settings.xml`, inside of `onCreate` or possibly `setContentView` replace `<include />` with the `content_home.xml` resource file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with the `include` tag, but with a [`ViewStub`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)

> A ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime. When a ViewStub is made visible, or when [inflate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html#inflate()) is invoked, the layout resource is inflated. The ViewStub then replaces itself in its parent with the inflated View or Views. Therefore, the ViewStub exists in the view hierarchy until [setVisibility(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html#setVisibility(int)) or [inflate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html#inflate()) is invoked. The inflated View is added to the ViewStub's parent with the ViewStub's layout parameters. Similarly, you can define/override the inflate View's id by using the ViewStub's inflatedId property.

In your scenario you would use [`setLayoutResource(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html#setLayoutResource(int)) just before you inflate the `ViewStub`.

Comment: Yeah, I just found out about the ViewStub as you were writing this, I implemented a test, and it does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the confirmation that this would be a good approach!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to inject a layout file into this include programatically inside of each activity

No, you cannot inject "into include" as include is not part of final layout (it just tells you want some other layout XML to be included here during building process).

What you can do however, is to add any "sub layout" (created from code or separately inflated from project layout file) to any existing ViewGroup in your "master layout", which is quite often used technique. [See ViewGroup docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), especially look closer at methods like `addView()`.

Alternatively to the aboive, you can consider using LayoutInflater's ([See docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)) `inflate()` method, where you can specify also root viewgroup for your newly inflated layout to be added to once inflated.

You can also (and perhaps that would be much better approach) consider separating components i.e. by using Fragments and then add fragments to your layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout instead of `<include>`

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In you Activities you can use LayoutInflater

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_home, null);
frameLayout.addView(layout);
```